# Why am I getting multiple http requests on my Angular app?

Tags: angular, http

I'm using Angular 5.2 and am having problems with a double load of the http request to my api's. This is causing the app trouble by only loading the partial view. I get all my requested data back.

I have done research and believe that perhaps both my server and browser apps are making the same request, which some people say Angular's 'TransferState' is a good way to solve. I tried to find a way to implement it (i.e.  [here](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/pull/509) but couldn't find a step by step tutorial.

If you think that that is indeed the problem, could someone help me find a way to implement a solution?

If I am wrong and I need to move on, could someone help me figure out why I seem to be making so many of the same requests to my api's?

Upon initial load/sign-in, My console in the app looks like:

```
 XHR finished loading: GET "https://my_api.com/auth/validate_token".
 XHR finished loading: GET "https://my_api.com/auth/validate_token".
 XHR finished loading: GET "https://my_api.com/sites.json".
 XHR finished loading: GET "https://my_api.com/sites.json".
 XHR finished loading: OPTIONS "<URL>".
 XHR finished loading: OPTIONS "https://my_api.com/auth/sign_in".
 XHR finished loading: OPTIONS "https://my_api.com/auth/validate_token".
 XHR finished loading: OPTIONS "https://my_api.com/auth/validate_token".zone.js:2019
 XHR finished loading: OPTIONS "https://my_api.com/sites.json". zone.js:2019 
 XHR finished loading: OPTIONS "https://my_api.com/sites.json".zone.js:2019
```

Does OPTIONS vs GET indicate anything?

My routes look like:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'sites', component: SitelistComponent },
 { path: 'sites/map', component: SitemapComponent },
 { path: 'site/create', component: CreatesiteComponent },
 { path: 'site/:id', component: SitepageComponent },
 { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
 { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/sites'},
];
```

app.module.ts:

```
  providers: [ DataService, NavigationComponent, Angular2TokenService, AuthService, AuthGuard,
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
{provide: 'api', useValue: 'https://my_api.com/'}
],
```

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
 production: false,
 token_auth_config: {
 apiBase: 'https://my_api.com'
}};
```

auth.service.ts

```
  getSites(){ 
    return this.authService.get(`sites.json`);
  }
```

(this above occurs once, not the issue)

Thanks! I'm still somewhat new with Angular and haven't had this happen before. Let me know if there's any more info I can provide!

***EDIT: My observable looks like:

```
  ngOnInit() {
   this.authService.getSites()
   .map((res:Response) => (
   res.json() 

   ))
   .subscribe(data => {
   this.sites = data
  })
```

where to put shareReplay()?

Note: I call this same thing ( getSites() ) in multiple components... is that my problem?

Or is it my use of {{ site.name }} multiple times?

Comment: are you using multiple async  pipes in your views to display the data from this.authService.get(`sites.json`) ? if so, and the authService.get call is just returning the http observable, then each time  you use async pipe it will cause another call to the api to be made. To avoid this add .shareReplay() to the observable that is returned.

Comment: Interesting I think you may be right. I edited my code above to show my observable. Could you help me figure out where to put it? And since I call getSites() in multiple components, does that number apply to the parameter I put in the shareReplay() ? Thanks

Comment: Whenever you subscribe to  http observable, request will be made.

Comment: Looks like I have a lot of refactoring to do. Thanks!

Comment: If you can add the code for the authService.getSites() method it will be easier to see where the shareReplay should go - if you haven't already sorted it yourself that is. Also, it would help to know if the list of sites only needs to be loaded once on the initial load of the app, or do you need a way to get a fresh list from the api during the app lifecycle

Comment: I don't need to get the list that many times, I just need the list on a couple of different components that are both children of the same parent. Which I suppose it would be much more efficient to just pass the list down to each after retrieving it in the parent. I assume that would be less strenuous

Comment: FYI: httpClient handles converting the object that comes back as a json, so you don't have to use .json()